# How can I use jquery to add class content

Tags: jquery

```
class="sc-up-header-search-menu hydrated"
```

I want to use jquery to change this class like that.

```
class="sc-up-header-search-menu hydrated open"
```

help me.

Comment: What did you try so far? Looks like you didn't even try. Please, consider looking at `jQuery` documentation, then try to solve the issue and only make a question if you are stuck. https://api.jquery.com/addClass/

Answer (score 0):

You can just use jquery's `addClass` method:

```
$('.sc-up-header-search-menu').addClass('open')
```

Or:

```
$('.hydrated').addClass('open')
```